sqlplus send two commands to the command line
I have tried both of these methods for sending two commands to the commandline with sqlplus. Neither are working. What am I doing wrong? I thought one of them would work.
sqlplus username/password@database @create_table_drop_table.sql
sqlplus username/password@database < create_table_drop_table.sql

As Alex mentioned in comments. Try this if you are having trouble. Go into your tnsnames.ora. Copy and paste the appropriate things.
sqlplus username/password@hostname:port/service_name @create_table_drop_table.sql
sqlplus username/password@hostname:port/service_name < create_table_drop_table.sql

This i my create_table_drop_table.sql file.
create table tab_5(id number, col1 varchar2(50), col2 varchar2(50));
drop table tab_5;

First Error messages.
sqlplus username/password@database @create_table_drop_table.sql
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Second Error messages.
sqlplus username/password@database < create_table_drop_table.sql
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]


What does create_table_drop_table.sql contain, and what does "neither are working" mean? What output or errors do you get?

@AlexPoole create table tab_5(id number, col1 varchar2(50), col2 varchar2(50)); drop table tab_5; 

Please edit the question to include that, formatted as it is in the file; and the output/error you get. If there is no exit then the second way you run it ought to work. Assuming the connection info is correct, of course.

@AlexPoole done. Why are you asking for this?

Because formatting things like that doesn't really work in comments, and what's in it might be relevant and ought to be a permanent part of the question rather than a comment that might be removed. Anyway... as it is, your second call with < ought to be fine (on Linux anyway). The first one should also work if you add exit to the end of your file so it doesn't wait for more input. You still haven't shown the output or errors you get though.

OK, well that error is nothing to do with your SQL script. You're connecting to @database, but it doesn't recognise database as an alias from your tnsnames.ora file. The file doesn't exist, or it can't find it, or it just doesn't have an entry for that.

@AlexPoole I see it in my tnsnames.ora file. Are there any tricks with giving it the full database name? Why does @pmdba method work below? Was just hoping for a one liner.

If pmdba's << heredoc version works then the < redirect should work too. Either you've specified the @database part slightly differently or there's something else you aren't doing quite as you've shown.

@AlexPoole how would I use the full database name? How would you turn the << heredoc into a one liner?

If it's in your tnsnames.ora you can see it there, but it should just work. You can use the easy-connect syntax instead if you know those details, e.g. :sqlplus username/password@hostname:port/service_name.

@AlexPoole that worked with the full hostname, port, and service name. Not sure why it is being difficult. Not seeing any typos. Thank you!!!!

From a *nix command line, try this:
sqlplus username/password@database << EOF
@create_table_drop_table.sql
exit
EOF

This assumes there is no explicit exit command in your sql file. If you already have exit in your SQL, then you would not need it in this script:
sqlplus username/password@database << EOF
@create_table_drop_table.sql
EOF

Note that if you don't include an explicit exit command either in your SQL script or in the OS command line input, sqlplus won't exit and the OS command will appear to hang (sqlplus is really waiting for the next command, which doesn't ever come).

do you know why my method does not work. I was hoping for a one liner.

You method isn't differentiating between the OS command line and the SQL command line within sqlplus. @create_table_drop_table.sql isn't a valid OS command-line option for sqlplus; similarly, create_table_drop_table.sql isn't itself a valid SQL command (it contains SQL commands). My method allows sqlplus to open the SQL command shell, and then process everything that follows (until EOF) as SQL commands.

The @create_table_drop_table.sql command0line syntax is fine? Except the file doesn't include an exit. That's handled as an argument by SQL*Plus... The redirect should also be fine. It's unclear why the TNS alias wasn't being recognised, but that seems to have been the only issue.
